# How to parrallellize a for loop in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have this loop and I'm wondering what are the different ways to parralelize it :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)){

    dataset$dayDiff[i] = dataset$close[i] - dataset$open[i]

}
```

I was thinking of using lapply but I don't see how to use a list in this context. Maybe I would use foreach in the parallel package but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good reason to use a loop here. Simply do `dataset$dayDiff <- dataset$close - dataset$open`. R is vectorized.

Comment: nice didn't know you could do that

Comment: Then you haven't read "An Introduction to R". Read it if you plan to use R in the future.